# How can I send out a flask-socketio to send a emit immediately instead of waiting for the process to finish

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, timing, flask-socketio

So all I really want to do is something like this

```
get a request from javascript in the form of socket.emit
immediately send out an emit("blah blah blah",{"data":"SomeData"},Broadcast=True)
```

then go on to do sleep or do other processing AFTER the first emit has been sent out.
This later processing will take lots and lots of time and possibly go on forever sending emits to the browser periodically
The issue is that the process won't send out the first request until everything is finished.

Comment: Maybe startup a separate thread? Kick off the thread then emit the message. If it’s really long running start it’s own process.

Comment: I understand that probably make sense and if this does not work will try that but for simplicity of writing this code is there something like emitNow()?

Comment: So I used a background thread, but I cannot emit from it from the error out of context. I read up a little and that I needed app.app_context().push() but now i get a new error AttributeError: __enter__.